# Implementing Fluent Builder Pattern for nested clases

Tags: c#, design-patterns, builder-pattern

I am trying to understand fluent builder patterns and in my case, I have an object that has child objects too. Most of the online examples are based on a single object. There are some examples for nested objects but they all are different. So I am here to find out what is the correct way to implement a fluent builder pattern for my case.

```
public class Controller
{
  private Robot _robot;
  private Table _table;              
  public Controller() {}
  public void Place() {}
  public void Action() {}
}

public class Robot
{
  private Point _currentLocation;
  public Robot(Point point) {}
  public void Move(){}
}

public class Table
{
  private int _width;
  private int _length;
  public Table(int width, int length){}
  public bool IsValidLocation(Point point){}
}
```

------------ Edited ----------

I have approached implementing this as below. Any expert advice on the below approach?

```
public class TableBuilder
{
    private readonly Table _table = new();

    public Table Build() => _table;

    public TableBuilder WithWidth(int width)
    {
        _table.Width = width;
        return this;
    }

    public TableBuilder WithLength(int length)
    {
        _table.Length = length;
        return this;
    }
} 

public class RobotBuilder
{
    private readonly Robot _robot = new();

    public Robot Build() => _robot;

    public RobotBuilder WithLocation(Point point)
    {
        _robot.CurrentLocation = point;
        return this;
    }
}

public class ControllerBuilder
{
    private readonly Controller _controller = new();
    private readonly TableBuilder _tableBuilder = new();
    private readonly RobotBuilder _robotBuilder = new();


    public Controller Build() => _controller;

    public ControllerBuilder WithTable(int width, int length)
    {
        _controller.Table = _tableBuilder.WithWidth(width)
                                        .WithLength(length)
                                        .Build();
        return this;
    }

    public ControllerBuilder WithRobot(Point point)
    {
        _controller.Robot = _robotBuilder.WithLocation(point)
                                        .Build();
        return this;
    }
}
```

Finally I used below code to declare the Controller

```
var _controller = new ControllerBuilder()
                    .WithRobot(new Point(x, y))
                    .WithTable(5, 5)
                    .Build();
```

Comment: For what objects do you want to apply Fluent pattern?

Comment: For the Controller class

Comment: Could you show your desirable call of chainable methods?

Comment: var result = new ControllerBuilder()
                     .WithRobot(point)
                     .WithTable(_with, _length)
                     .Build();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I usually do in this cases is to use nested builders with lambdas, which are useful when the nested classes have many parameters needed at construction time:

```
public class Controller
{
    private readonly Robot _robot;
    private readonly Table _table;

    public Controller(Robot robot, Table table)
    {
        _robot = robot;
        _table = table;
    }

    public void Place()
    {
    }

    public void Action()
    {
    }
}

public class Robot
{
    private Point _currentLocation;

    public Robot(Point point)
    {
    }

    public void Move()
    {
    }
}

public class Table
{
    private readonly int _width;
    private readonly int _length;

    public Table(int width, int length)
    {
        _width = width;
        _length = length;
    }


    public bool IsValidLocation(Point point)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class TableBuilder
{
    private int _width;
    private int _length;
    public TableBuilder WithWidth(int width)
    {
        _width = width;
        return this;
    }

    public TableBuilder WithLength(int length)
    {
        _length = length;
        return this;
    }

    public Table Build() => new Table(_width, _length);
}

public class RobotBuilder
{
    private Point _location;

    public Robot Build() => new Robot(_location);

    public RobotBuilder WithLocation(Point location)
    {
        _location = location;
        return this;
    }
}

public class ControllerBuilder
{
    private Robot _robot;
    private Table _table;


    public Controller Build() => new Controller(_robot, _table);

    public ControllerBuilder WithRobot(Func<RobotBuilder, RobotBuilder> builderDirector)
    {
        _robot = builderDirector.Invoke(new RobotBuilder()).Build();
        return this;
    }

    public ControllerBuilder WithTable(Func<TableBuilder, TableBuilder> builderDirector)
    {
        _table = builderDirector(new TableBuilder()).Build();
        return this;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var controller = new ControllerBuilder()
            .WithTable(builder => builder.WithLength(1).WithWidth(2))
            .WithRobot(builder => builder.WithLocation(new Point(1,1)))
            .Build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fluent pattern works as class returns the type of class. So we can return `this`.

Let me show an example. `ControllerBuilder` would look like this:

```
public class ControllerBuilder
{
    Controller _controller = new();

    public ControllerBuilder WithRobot(Point point) 
    {

        return this;
    }

    public ControllerBuilder WithTable(int width, int length)
    {
        // your code here
        return this;
    }

    public ControllerBuilder Build() 
    {
        // your code here
        return _controller;
    }
}
```

and `Controller` class:

```
public class Controller
{
    private Robot _robot;
    private Table _table;
    public Controller() { }
    public void Place() { }
    public void Action() { }
}
```

and other classes:

```
public class Robot
{
    private Point _currentLocation;
    public Robot(Point point) { }
    public void Move() { }
}

public class Table
{
    private int _width;
    private int _length;
    public Table(int width, int length) { }
    public bool IsValidLocation(Point point) { return true; }
}

public class Point { }
```

And then you can chain your methods like this:

```
var result = new ControllerBuilder()
    .WithRobot(new Point())
    .WithTable(1, 2)
    .Build();
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort and the answer. 

Shouldn't you want to return the Controller object from the ControllerBuilder class?

As you returning ControllerBuilder, I would not be able to use other methods in the Controller class. Ex. Action()    

following your approach and an online article, I implemented the Builder class and added the code above to my question. 

What do you think?

Comment: @Ash yeah, I am sorry for the typo. I've edited my reply. Please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

To ease the maintenance of a fluent API I created a tool, Java::Geci.

Using this tool you create a simple class with methods that set the values and the tool will generate a wrapper class for chaining and all the interfaces that restrict the order of the methods you can apply one after the other.

You can define your fluent API grammar over the methods using fluent API (well, eat your own dog food), but it can also be specified in a String using a "regular expression" over the methods instead of characters.

Obviously, I am a bit biased as I created this tool (Apache 2.0 license), but here it is:

https://github.com/verhas/javageci/blob/master/FLUENT.md